# Reference to PDF-file after JavaFX program is built

Tags: java, javafx

I have a program that is working perfectly when I run it from the IDE.
However, when I make an executable jar it cannot find two of the PDF files I have in a sub folder in source folder.

How should I reference to these files?

My project structure is: 
resources (source folder) 
- PdfTemplates (normal folder) 
- - myyntiPohja.pdf 
- - ostoPohja.pdf

When I run the program from the IDE I get java.io.File with the following reference: 
File offerDocument = new File("resources/PdfTemplates/ostoPohja.pdf"); 
and 
File offerDocument = new File("resources/PdfTemplates/myyntiPohja.pdf"); 

This works fine until I compile the project either with Export -> Runnable Jar file or with build.fxbuild -> ant build.xml and run.

Could someone please tell me what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that there is no such file. Your resource is now bundled in the jar file, so it isn't even represented as a file at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new File("resources/PdfTemplates/ostoPohja.pdf")` search `resources` folder in current folder then search `PdfTemplates` in it and `ostoPohja.pdf` in result of previouse search.

You shold have those folder structure next to your `jar` if you run double clicking on it.

Other option is you can embed those files into your `jar` file (which you most probably already did) then you should load them like this `Thread.currentThread().getClassloader().loadResourceAsStream(("resources/PdfTemplates/myyntiPohja.pdf")` and then utileze this stream instead of file.

Comment: This worked. I used InputStream offerDocument = PdfPrinter.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("PdfTemplates/myyntiPohja.pdf"). Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason that you can't use the full directory of the pdfs? Example:

> C:/Users/*Your Username*/Path/to/template.pdf

Comment: The reason is that if I don't include PDFs to my Jar file, I need to place these files on a public drive which will cause performance issues in the tool.

Answer (score 0):

You  have to use |NAME_OF_YOUR_CLASS|.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("PATH_TO_FILE_RELATIVE_TO_ROOT_OF_PROJECT".

The above returns an InputStream Object.  This can be used like so:

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileInputStream(*));

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Problem with a PDF file that could not be shown after building a jpackage .exe.

My solution now is to copy the PDF into the jpackage-build folder using gradle:

```
tasks.jpackageImage.doLast {
    copy {
        from "src/main/resources"
        include "my-file.pdf"
        into "build/jpackage/$project.name/src/main/resources"
    }
}
```

And in the JAVA code I can open the PDF using:

```
File file = new File("src/main/resources/my-file.pdf");
hostServices.showDocument(file.getAbsolutePath());
```